# split function in Javascript not working on string from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, javascript-objects

Giving this in js:

```
let data={"vets":[{"id": 1,"lt": "6","ln": 2702,"ls": "2011-07-02T00:00:00"}]};
```

I want to use the `split()` function on the `ls` property.

`data['vets'].ls` is giving the value: "2011-07-02T00:00:00".

I save it to a variable like this:

`let str = data['vets'].ls;`

When i run `str.split('T')[0]` to get only `2011-07-02`, i get an error of:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null`

**Edit:**
The array i have is about 3000 items. I am using the map() functionn to go on all of them like this:

```
data['vets'].map(function(vet){
   let str = vet['ls'];
   let short = str.split('T');
   vet['ls'] = short[0];
})
```

What can be the reason for it? 
Thanks.

Comment: It should be `data['vets'][0].ls` because `data['vets']` is an array.

Comment: `data['vets'].ls` is not returning `"2011-07-02T00:00:00"`, it's returning `undefined` since `vets` is an array.

Comment: The array is for more than 3000 items. @CuongLeNgoc

Comment: @GabMic do you want to split all of the items then? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want to split just the `ls` property. @AlexanderLomia

Comment: How many elements are in the array is irrelevant to your question...unless you aren't fully explaining your situation. Maybe start with providing more context?

Comment: I will update the question. @CrayonViolent

Comment: @GabMic okay I think I still don't understand your issue. At face value your code does what you seem to expect: change `ls` "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS" to just "YYYY-MM-DD"  https://i.imgur.com/lsvVOp2.png

Comment: That is why i cant seem to find out why i get the error. I am checking now by the answers i got below. @CrayonViolent

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @GabMic my guess is one of the elements in your array may not have an `ls` property

Comment: @str I will update it ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

Try `data['vets'][0].ls.split('T')[0]`.

In other words, you need to first access the first child of the `data[vets]` array and perform a `split` on its `ls` field. What you are doing instead, is calling split on an `ls` property of the array itself, which is indeed `undefined`.

**To get only the "date" part from each item:**

```js
let data = {"vets":[{"id": 1,"lt": "6","ln": 2702,"ls": "2011-07-02T00:00:00"}]};

console.log(data.vets.map(entry => entry.ls.split('T')[0]));

// shorter version which does the same thing
console.log(data.vets.map(({ ls }) => ls.split('T')[0]));
```

**To create a new array of items with modified `ls` fields:**

```js
let data = {"vets":[{"id": 1,"lt": "6","ln": 2702,"ls": "2011-07-02T00:00:00"}]};

// splits every item into two variables: `ls` and `rest`. `ls` is a string, 
// whereas `rest` is an object containing all of the fields of the original
// item. Using these variables, modified objects are created and assembled
// into a new array in an immutable way (the original data is not altered)
console.log(data.vets.map(({ ls, ...rest }) => ({
  // replaces the `ls` field's value
  ls: ls.split('T')[0],
  // includes all the other properties untouched
  ...rest,
})));
```

Comment: The giving item above is just the first item in a larger (3000) items. i am using the map function to run on all of them. How can i deal with it in that case?